# Confused about some java syntax

Tags: java, syntax

I am learning Java (slowly) from the ground up, but every now and again I peak at some "real" code and I found something that confused me.

The following line and ones like it:

```
JPanel panel = (JPanel) container.getContentPane();
```

My question is what is happening between `(JPanel)` and `container.getContentPane()`? Its not like they are being multiplied right?

I know this is a basic part of the language and as I continue learning I'll get to this part, but I got really curious and wanted to know what it was right away. I didn't really know what to google to get the answer.

Comment: I suggest to just work yourself through the *entire* basic Java tutorial/book. Here's Oracle's own one on the subject you're currently asking about: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: So is what's returned by container.getContentPane() being cast as a JPanel object?

Comment: Its a way for the programmer to tell Java Compiler to be convinced that whatever 'container.getContentPane()' returns *can be safely* treated as a  `JPanel`. Without this , by itself Java Compiler thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Its not like they are being multiplied right?

No. It means "get this thing and treat it as a JPanel." It's called type casting and that syntax is used in C++, C# and many other languages.

You have to make sure that the way that the classes are related to each other allows for casting. For example, this wouldn't work:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JComponent c = (JComponent)p;
JButton b = (JButton)c;
```

`JPanel` is a `JComponent` and so is `JButton`, but `JButton` does not descend from `JPanel` thus you cannot cast between these objects. You can also cast from a child back to a parent, such as from `JSpinner.DefaultEditor` back to `JPanel`, but not from `JPanel` to `JSpinner.DefaultEditor`.

Comment: Neato, that makes perfect sense to me now. I didn't get to casting yet in my java book, but I remember it in some other langauages I've played with. I guess the syntax should have be more familiar to me.

Comment: Note that a check is done at runtime to check if the cast is valid (i.e. if the thing that's being cast really can be treated as the type you're casting it to). If it is not, you will get a `ClassCastException` on the line where you do the cast. Also, casting should be avoided as much as possible, because it takes away type safety.

Answer (score 1):

It's a cast expression (see [JLS 15.16, Cast Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.16)).

It means "treat the results of the `getContentPane()` call as a `JPanel`".

Casts can fail, causing a `ClassCastException` (see [JLS 5.5, Casting Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5)).

Answer (score 1):

This is called a type cast. The method `getContentPane()` normally return a Container, but we want to get it in a JPanel so we'll be able to use JPanel methods. Of course the two types have to be compatible (JPanel is a specific implementation of Container (through JComponent) for example)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is how type casting is made in java. As you know java works with references. In your case you have a  JPanel type reference and container.getContentPane() returns (correct me if I am wrong my Swing is a bit rusty) container, so since those two are incompatible you need to type cast to make them compatible. Hope that helps